# can't use imported var from js file in code

Tags: javascript, html, variables, web, scope

I try to use imported vars from a `js` file into my code but I can't get it to work the excepted way.

**location_var.js**

```
var location = {

    place: "Bogotá",
    lat: "4.710988599999999",
    lng: "-74.072092"

};
export { location };
```

**index.html**

```
<script type="module">
    import { location } from './location_var.js'
    console.log(location.lat) // this will be displayed
</script>
```

but if I put a `<script>` tag below, I can't use my variables back.

```
<body>
    <!--The div element for the map -->
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
        function initMap() {
            var place = { lat: location.lat, lng: location.lng }; // this doesn't work - console says the vars are undefined for some reasons
            var map = new google.maps.Map(
                document.getElementById('map'), { zoom: 4, center: place });
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: place, map: map });
        }
    </script>
    <script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&callback=initMap">
        </script>
</body>
```

Any ideas why I can't call it back there?

Comment: If I change my lower `script` type tag the code blows up - `index.html:1 Uncaught (in promise) Xc {message: "initMap is not a function", name: "InvalidValueError", stack: "Error↵    at new Xc (https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYKEY&callback=initMap:125:107"}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variables defined (or imported) in modules have scope *only* in that module. If a `<script type="module">` defines or imports something, it won't be visible in any other `<script>` tag.

Unlike normal scripts, variable names defined with `const` / `let` / `var` and function declarations do not get put into the global environment, so even if you were to put the imported `location` into a standalone variable, it wouldn't help.

Another issue is that you have *two* asynchronous actions going on here: you have to get `location_var.js` to get the `location` object, and you also have to wait for the googleapis script to be downloaded. Neither script depends on the other, but you want to run something (initialize the map) after *both* have completed. To wait for multiple asynchronous things to finish and then run something else, you should use `Promise.all`, and to use `Promise.all`, you need to make sure each asynchronous action resolves a Promise once it's done. So, here's one possible approach:

```
<script>
window.googleScriptPromise = new Promise((resolve) => {
  window.googleScriptCallback = resolve;
});
window.locationPromise = new Promise((resolve) => {
  window.locationResolve = resolve;
});

Promise.all([
  locationPromise
  googleScriptPromise,
])
  .then(([location]) => {
    // now, location will refer to the imported location, and google maps will have been loaded
  });
</script>

<script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&callback=googleScriptCallback">
    </script>
<script type="module">
  import { location } from './location_var.js'
  window.locationPromise(location);
</script>
```

That preserves your current `<script>` structure, but it relies on a bunch of global variables. It would probably be a lot better if you didn't have a separate `<script>` tag for the bulk of the code, and instead put most of it in the module, that way you only have to call `.then` on the Google promise:

```
<script>
// must use a normal script tag to assign the Promise to window synchronously
window.googleScriptPromise = new Promise((resolve) => {
  window.googleScriptCallback = resolve;
});
</script>
<script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&callback=googleScriptCallback">
    </script>
<script type="module">
import { location } from './location_var.js'
window.googleScriptPromise.then(() => {
  // now, location will refer to the imported location, and google maps will have been loaded
});
</script>
```

If you're able to change where the bulk of your `<script>` is, the above approach is cleaner and definitely preferable.